# How to insert a new line in a text file using C++

Tags: io, turbo-c++

I have to write a program in C++ that asks user to enter lines and store them in a text file.

```
void create_file(char name[80])
{
char line[80],op;
ofstream fout(name);
do
{
    cout << "Enter the line you want to enter in the file:" << endl << endl;
    gets(line);
    fout << line << endl;
    cout << "\nDo you want to enter another line?" << endl;
    cin >> op;
}
while(tolower(op) == 'y');
cout << "File created successfully!" << endl;
fout.close();
}
```

The problem is that the text is not being stored in different lines.

**I have to use Turbo C++ for this program.**

Minimal, Reproducible Example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std;
void show(char name[80])
{
    char line[800];
    cout << "Contents of the file:" << endl << endl;
    ifstream fin (name);
    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        fin.getline(line,80);
        if(fin.eof())
            break;
        cout << line;
    }
}
void create_file(char name[80])
{
    char line[80],op;
    ofstream fout(name);
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the line you want to enter in the file:" << endl << endl;
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(line);
        fout << line << endl;
        cout << "\nDo you want to enter another line?" << endl;
        fflush(stdin);
        cin >> op;
    }
    while(tolower(op) == 'y');
    cout << "File created successfully!" << endl;
    fout.close();
    show(name);
}
int main()
{
    char name1[80];
    cout <<"Enter the name of the text file:" << endl;
    gets(name1);
    create_file(name1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but use `std::string line;` instead of `char line[80]` and `std::getline(std::cin, line);` instead of `gets(line);`.

Comment: if you open your output file and hex view it what separators between lines it have: 10 or 13 or 13,10 or 10,13  ? the usual is `0x13,0x10` or `0D 0A` in hex so you either do not store line separator as you should or your viewer does not recognize it correctly ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo IIRC there is no std in old turbo... std was created only after Turbo C++ was made

Comment: @Spektre That might be true but I think I've seen other users of Turbo C++ use `std` so they are _hopefully_ using a newer version.

Comment: @TedLyngmo hmm brownsing its files I see `stdlib.h` and some other `std` prefixed files but that is not the same as `std::` you know today

Comment: @Spektre It's likely a port of the early STL then. I found this [Turbo C++ 3.2 image](https://github.com/vineetchoudhary/turbocpp/blob/master/screenshot/tfull.png?raw=true). It seems like someone is repackaging 3.2 for modern Windows versions. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo hmm OP author clearly does not have such version ... and I do not think (s)he can force the school to go for it ...

Comment: @Dhruv Which version of Turbo C++ are you using exactly? If you can't find out yourself, you could ask your teacher. Also, make a [mcve] program so we can see what headers you use etc. I suspect `<iostream.h>` will be there...

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have added a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Also, I am using Turbo C++ version 3.0. PS: I tried the code in code::blocks too and have the same problem. I STILL HAVE TO USE TURBO C++.

Comment: @DhruvTyagi You should check that you successfully opened the file before writing to it: `ofstream fout(name); if(fout) { /* success */ } else { /* failure */ }`
Does your version of Turbo C++ support `std::string` and `std::getline()`?

Comment: And don't use `while(!fin.eof())` when reading the file. Do `while( std::getline(fin, line) ) {...}` and then you can remove the `eof` test inside the loop too.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but Turbo C++ and C++ are different languages with very different programming idioms and techniques ...

Comment: Can you please open the text file and share a screenshot of what is in it? It probably takes a number of spaces as a new line (like 20 spaces).